# Does the order of function definition matter in list patterns

Tags: list, function, haskell, pattern-matching, definition

So these function orders have different behaviour in GHCI:

```
safetailpatter xs = tail xs
safetailpatter [] = []
```

```
safetailpatter [] = []
safetailpatter xs = tail xs
```

The former generates the following warning and the following error when passing in `[]`

```
ex3.hs:66:1: warning: [-Woverlapping-patterns]
    Pattern match is redundant
    In an equation for ‘safetailpatter’: safetailpatter [] = ...
```

```
*** Exception: Prelude.tail: empty list
```

As such does the order of definition matter and why? I don't see why the former overlaps while the latter doesn't as the same definitions are given.

Comment: the order matters with any patterns, not just list patterns. it matters  because the patterns are considered in top-down order, not simultaneously. hypothetically they could be considered simultaneously, in non-specified order or in no order at all i.e. concurrently, sparking simultaneous computations for each branch. Dijkstra e.g. envisioned such a language, where the first (in time, not order) branch to match would proceed and the others would be killed. or a language could proceed with all of them until a result is produced from one (or from all, like Prolog). but Haskell is deterministic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Patterns are matched in order. But, what's going on here is that you are not actually parttern matching on `safetailpatter xs`.

In regular english `safetailpatter xs = tail xs` means: *safetailpatter on any variable is tail of that variable*.

What you want to match is: `safetailpatter (x:xs) = tail (x:xs)`, which stands for: *safetailpatter when applied on a list with at least one element, is tail of such a list*

Knowing this, In the code

```
safetailpatter xs = tail xs
safetailpatter [] = []
```

Will check in order, and because the first equation matches any list input, you get a runtime error on `[]`. Whereas

```
safetailpatter (x:xs) = tail xs
safetailpatter [] = []
```

matches in order, and since  `[]` doesn't match the first equation, It'll run the second, with no runtime error

#### Edit

As @chepner says, this is call *irrefutable pattern*. Meaning that pattern matching is happening but there is no chance to fail. Same as if you match against `_`

Comment: Oh, you are right, you can just leave that order when pattern matching on `(x:xs)`, good point.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `xs` is an *irrefutable* pattern. Pattern matching is happening, but there is no way for the match to fail: it will match any argument passed to the function.

Answer (score 8):

`xs` also match the empty list, so `safetailpatter []` will never be called if you place `safetailpatter xs` first.

I am pretty new to Haskell, but I think that is what is happening.

So, when you place `safetailpatter xs` first and then call it with an empty list, you are trying to call `tail` on the empty list, and you get the exception.

As for

```
Pattern match is redundant
    In an equation for ‘safetailpatter’: safetailpatter [] = ...
```

I think it means basically what I described above, it is complaining that the declaration is redundant because `safetailpatter []` is already covered by `safetailpatter xs` when you put the latter one first.

That is the reason why you should always place `_` at the end of your pattern matching definitions, other-way you the rest of the patterns will never get called:

```
myF (x:xs) = -- ....
myF _ = -- ...        -> Right
```

```
myF _ = -- ...        -> Wrong, now no the bellow definition will never get called
myF (x:xs) = -- ....
```

Comment: Yup, that's it indeed.

Comment: Agreed, but sometimes you can't use `_` in the last pattern because you need to bind some variable. E.g. `foo (Left x) = f x ; foo (Right y) = g y`.